# Finding Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo and ConnectionInfo References that are Compatible

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, dll

I'm trying to use

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common    
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo
```

And I successfully found the .dll files on my C: drive in the usual place,

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
```

The problem is that apparently the two aren't compatible.

`.Smo` comes from `\130\SDK\Assemblies` 
and

`.Common` comes from referencing the `.ConnectionInfo.dll` from `\110\SDK\Assemblies`

so I wonder since they're not in the same `\number\SDK\Assemblies` that's why they aren't the same version.  When I run the application I get this message from Visual Studio

> "Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed."

And

> "Assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' uses 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'"

I tried to do what Microsoft suggest which is set AutoGenerateBindingRedirects to true but that did not work.

**ASK:**
 Where would I go to find the proper versions of the dlls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see both dlls in the same directory on my SQL Server installation:

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
```

Using VS 2015 with .net 4.5.2 I'm able to reference both dlls, build, and run a console app that uses the `ServerConnection` and `Server` classes.

See if you can find the `Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll` in the 110\SDK folder.

Comment: I swear I checked all those folders for both but alas they were both in there.  However I'm still getting a version issue when trying to run when both are referenced from `\110`

Comment: So I fixed the error I was getting by also adding `Sdk.Sfc.dll` to references as well because it was apparently missing that

Comment: @BlueBarren Glad to hear the problem is resolved, you're right all referenced SQL SDK assemblies will need to be of compatible versions

Answer (score 1):

You can either install the Client Tools SDK when installing sql server or use the [Sql Server Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676) and choose either ENU\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi or ENU\x86\SharedManagementObjects.msi from the list of components

Comment: When installing the `ENU\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi` I didn't notice an install path, where would the `.dlls` I need be located after the install?

Comment: I think you were looking in the correct place, you didn't have all of the components installed.   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\SDK\Assemblies\

Comment: though for some reason ConnectionInfo seems to be in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2016\x64

Comment: Both of the `.dlls` aren't in 130 still... and `\Setup Boostrap` is empty for me aside from a `\bin` folder which is empty

Comment: According to this article for 2016 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162161.aspx) ConnectionInfo gets installed to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\.

Comment: I don't have `\120` ... I only have `\80`,`\90`,`\100`,`\110`,`\130`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122850/discussion-between-bluebarren-and-miniver-cheevy).

Comment: Update 12May2022. The SMO is now installed via Nuget: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/installing-smo?view=sql-server-ver15